# How to delete remote branch (e.g. Github) from command line?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository in my local machine:
I add a new branch called `test` and add a few commits
Then I checkout to `master` branch and add commits to it.
So I use `git push --all github` and continue working on master.
After some time I decide to completely remove the `test` branch and use: `git branch -d test` and `git branch -r -d github/test`, but it only deletes the local branch used for tracking the actual `test` branch as git says:

> Deleted remote-tracking branch github/buggy (was acc5a58).

I'm asking if there's a way to actually remove the `test` branch from github servers from command-line?

Comment: A answer already answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely

Comment: @GSkidmore, yes and thanks. I haven't found that post in my previous searches and had to ask my own. `:)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As with every `git` server:

```
$ git push github :<BRANCH_NAME>
```

or:

```
$ git push github --delete <BRANCH_NAME>
```

Example:

```
$ git push github --delete test
```

Comment: For future readers - if you want to list all the remote branches (in Github) try: `git branch -r`

Comment: Not only in Github, it's git feature. And each basic git tutorial describes it.

Answer (score 72):

**Local Branch**

```
git branch -D local_branch
```

**Remote Branch**

```
git push origin --delete remote_branch
```

Comment: `git push origin :remote_branch`

Comment: For the deleting local branch, the delete flag should be uppercase. Like this `git branch -D local_branch`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Updated!

Comment: `git push origin :remote_branch` only works if you've deleted the local branch.  The answer as posted is better, since it treats the two cases independently.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
git push github :test
```

Read "push nothing as refname `test` on github remote"